# Why does adding callback typehint in php 7 trigger deprecation Warning

Tags: php, callback, php-7, type-hinting

I have the code below. Fairly simple stuff. However, it gives a warning: `Deprecated: Non-static method Foo::bar() should not be called statically in test.php on line 13`
If I add a typehint to the $method parameter (e.g. callable $method) then I get 2 warnings. If I remove the typehint, no warning. It also actually seems to trigger the spl autoloading process (if it were needed).

Anybody have any idea why? Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
<?php
class Foo
{

    public function bar()
    {
        echo 'baz';
    }
}

function justReturn($method): callable
{
    return $method;
}

justReturn([Foo::class, 'bar']);
```

Answer (score 0):

`bar` is not a static method, so it needs to be called through an object, e.g.

```
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar();
```

If you want it to be callable without an object, you need to declare it static.

```
static public function bar() {
    echo "baz";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but you missed the point. It's obvious that it's not static and it's not supposed to be. Indeed, for it to be callable it would need to be static, or the first part should be the instance of the object. The question is why it works if not typehint exists for  "justReturn" function, and gives warning if typehint is set? Because as you can see, I don't make any actual calls to the method bar()

Comment: Just realized I sort-of answered my own question. The method is not really static, and I assume adding the typehint will test to see it exists/is correct. Thanks for pointing me towards the answer